# Memcached failover technique

Tags: .net, memcached, memcache

We have 2 memcached servers configured and use the Eniym client. When one of the server is down, it appears this server is added to the deadServers list (ServerPool.cs) and tries to resurrect the server every 10seconds (we have configured deadTimeOut to be 10seconds). Attempting to connect to the failed server causes a TCP timeout, the pages take a long time to load which results in bad user experience.

1) What is the standard way of resolving this issue? There are some posts about removing the server from the deadServers list. Is it okay to do this?

2) What is the recommended deadTimeOut setting (I understand by default it's 2 mins and we've changed it to 10seconds in our implementation)

3) Am I correct in my understanding that the cached data is not replicated across Server 1 and Server 2? If Server 1 is down, then it goes to the database to fetch these values (and it doesn't really check Server2)?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assessment is mostly correct.  I can't speak for your client, but a downed server shouldn't affect you in normal operations.

That is to say, you don't want failover, replication, etc... you just want your client to behave properly when a failure occurs.